# LibreOffice: print and export to pdf always half size

Tags: printing, libreoffice, pdf

When printing or exporting to pdf in LibreOffice 5.1 my pages are scaled down by 50%. Always. Even when I print 2 pages on 1 then each separate page is scaled down.

It never happened before, until this week. I haven't installed any new printer. To be sure, I deleted all printers, but it didn't help.

In Calc I seem to solve it by checking the box 'Fit print ranges to width/height' 1:1 in Format/Page/Sheet. But I can't find the same option in Writer. Under Export to Pdf / Initial View I can change magnification, but that doesn't help.

I use Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, with Lubuntu, and I think I use the LibreOffice that came with the first installation (though updated since, of course). I don't know where to find information about my pdf driver.

Comment: What pdf driver option are you using? Please edit your question to include.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Are you using the LibreOffice that came with Ubuntu? If not how did you install it?

Comment: There are 3 ways to create a PDF from LibreOffice writer. (1) File > Export... menu. (2) Export as PDF button. (3) File > Print... Print to File option. Are you facing this problem in all 3?

Comment: Yes. And also when I print. But there is news. Today I discovered that I was still working in LibreOffice versio 5, so I updated to 6.2 and it's over now. That's good news. But it's still strange, in 5 the problem started suddenly, and I'm not sure that it won't happen again.